# Dynamic sub domains with angular

Tags: angular, subdomain, angular-routing, angularfire

I am using Angular

For our project we need multi tenancy support for URLs with sub domains.

We have product similar to Slack and each our tenant (client) has its own isolated database, so we want him to access our product via:

```
client1.myproject.com
client2.myproject.com
client3.myproject.com
```

etc. How to do that in Angular? We know angular routing can only change the path and not the domain. Is it even supported at all or not?

Thanks!

P.S: This is the re-asking of my previous question which wasn't asked as it should have been.

Comment: so did you get the answer ?? i also want to implement same functionality but with dynamic  sub-domain . and how can we implement it in angular7 project @saad-ashfaq

Answer (score 6):

To test on development environment you need to do some settings in your host file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).
You can add list of domains in it that will pointed to your localhost & serve your application.

```
ng serve --host client1.myproject.com --port 4200 --open
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can i add  *.app.com, means dynamic subdomain in my hosts. or do i need to add each subdomain manually?

Comment: No, you can't add domain names dynamically you have to add each domain name manually.

Comment: It is not a functional solution, use, instead, the root ... myproject.com ... --disable-host-check
and --disable-host-check

Answer (score 3):

To enable dynamic hosting, just run the app via this command

```
ng serve --o --live-reload --ssl true --disable-host-check
```

after running app and open new browser tab and write i.e. `abc.localhost:4200` and your are done.

> You may get browser security alert just ignore it and proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it, we are doing it. with different domains but same application.

basically just make some config service that you get your data set from by the
domain.
And then set your application with the "company" you want(by the domain).

for example:

```
 constructor() {
        this.currentURL = window.location.href;
        if (this.currentURL.indexOf('company1') >= 0)
            this.setParamsCompany1();
        else if(this.currentURL.indexOf('company2') >= 0)
            this.setParamsCompany2();
    }
```

Comment: Okay i understand the solution. But how can i test it on my development environment (localhost). 
And second thing. I have two ways to go to the sub domain. one is by manually putting the name in the URL e.g: client1.myapp.com and the second thing is by taking input on the signin page e.g: myapp.com/signin. So should i give an absolute link using window.location.href to redirect to the page if the user confirmed. or is there any other way. And how to do it on development environment. 

I hope i explained it properly.

Comment: On your localhost its kinda hard to test it, but its possible if you know how to set your local vhosts with few domains to the localhost:4200.
p.s not 100% sure it works with angular, I know it works with Xammp\Wamp etc.


for your second question it, does not matter .
just make sure you use this config to set up the rest of the application after user login or when ever you need to do it.

Comment: @SaadAshfaq is there a reason you dont give me + for the answer? or u just want people to answer and u run away.

Comment: sorry for the late response, i tried your suggestions. It works. But i'm finding it difficult to manage the state of my application as well as the sessions, as localStorage is only stored for a specific domain. I found out different solutions (iFrame etc.) but nothing seems to work perfectly. I wanna know how did you manage these things in your Angular application. Can you show me your work?

P.S: You were very helpful. Thanks for that. An since my reputation is less than 15 so it doesn't change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @SaadAshfaq we create config service which we pull from everything importent per client.

Answer (score -3):

The default schema routing for Angular is http://example.com/client1. Due to framework logic (or business model, like you want to say it), your request is impossible to do.

Comment: What will you recommend to implement such thing? Do i need to do sever side rendering? Because currently i have a server less architecture.